# My Mac machine is extremely slow all of sudden?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, hardware, software

It was functioning very well until all of a sudden it went extremely slow, I still had a good size of hard disk space and to top it off I reset, wiped out entire disk and reinstalled the OS, even after doing that  it is still slow, looks like a hardware issue, but i may be wrong.

What can I do to fix this?

*MacBook Pro 13″, 2017 (two thunderbolt 3 ports), macOS 10.15*

***I am trying to figure out how can I fixed this sudden speed lost of my Mac,it turns out that certain IC was and capacitors (thingy) were burned.***

I think(not 100% sure) that the cause of issue was I was using a converted that provides hdmi, then was converting that hdmi to vga, then connecting to an old monitor, that converter looked something like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: [Diagnose problems with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/diagnose-problems-mh35727/mac)

Comment: Check Activity Monitor to see what, if anything, is using lots of CPU or Memory. It's much more likely to be software (that you've installed) which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a recent problem like that and it was because my disks were failing. My machine is a 2010 iMac though. I don't expect this to be the cause for you. But just to be sure you can run [Drive DX](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) an app to check the health of your drive. The app is not free but they have a free trial. If your disk is fine, I suggest [EtreCheck](https://www.etrecheck.com). This app will tell you the status of your machine and generate a report about the info it finds. It told me my speed was well below the standard speed of my computer type. It also pointed out possible reasons for the speed drop. Etrecheck also has a free trial.

As a final step to quantify your speed drops by running [Geekbench](https://www.geekbench.com), which is an app that calculates the speed of your chips by running a few minutes' worths of tests. If gives you a single core and multicore scores and compares them with benchmarks for your machine type and you can compare your scores with scores from many others. This will give you some proof of your slowdown as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am in process with the apple support, i may try this if apple support doesn't help, cheers  .^_^.

Comment: OK, let me know how it goes if you don't mind.  Just put your results in a new comment..